# Mostrar estado activo según section I’d

Tags: javascript, css, html5

hola buen dia estoy trabajando una landing page y programe un smooth scroll usando js vanilla y los problemas son
**primer problema**
tengo una navbar fija y quiero mostrarle al usuario donde esta, algo como esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que funcione si no le doy click al boton,que sea automatico si hago scroll hasta la seccion contactos el navbar muestre el boton en activo

**mi segundo problema**
es que cuando hago click me lleva muy abajo de la seccion y no me muestra el titulo de la seccion adjunto imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y deberia de quedar asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo js y html para el smooth scroll es este

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar ul a");

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");

  document.querySelector(href).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start",
  });
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <i class="fal fa-meteor" id="logo"></i>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#inicio" id="inicio">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#categorias" id="categoriasnav">Categorias</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#masvendidos" id="masvendidosnav">Mas Vendidos</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contactanos" id="contactanosnav">Contactanos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id='home'>
      <h1>home</h1>
    </section>

    <section id='categorias'>
      <h1>categorias</h1>
    </section>

    <section id='masventas'>
      <h1>top de ventas</h1>
    </section>

    <section id='contactanos'>
      <h1>contactanos</h1>
    </section>
```

desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda
**nota** no puedo usar librerias,solo vanilla js

Comment: **Tercer problema:** Los ID deben ser únicos y tienes 4 elementos con `id="navbutton"`

Comment: @Triby gracias, habia olvidado cambiarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una pequeña función que chequee si los elementos respectivos (en este caso tus secciones) se encuentran dentro del [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport) del usuario. La función retorna **true** si está dentro del Viewport respectivo.

```
function isInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const html = document.documentElement;
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || html.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

Luego, necesitas crear un id o una clase única para el elemento del nav, y en base a eso encontrar los nodos de la sección y el nav correspondiente

```
const categoriesSection = document.getElementById("categories");
const categoriesNav = document.getElementById("categories-nav");
```

Finalmente, puedes añadirle un event listener de tipo [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) al navegador, y llamar a la función creada. Si la sección está dentro del Viewport, puedes agregarle la clase **active** al nav respectivo

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
  const categoriesIsInViewport = isInViewport(categoriesSection);
  if (categoriesIsInViewport) {
    categoriesNav.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    categoriesNav.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

Puedes hacer esto con cada elemento de tu nav

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono!